# How to automatically expand all nodes of a PreferenceManager

Tags: java, swt, jface

To manage preferences of my swt/jface application, I'm using `org.eclipse.jface.preference`

I have 3 nodes in the preference window:

```
    //Creation of the nodes
    PreferenceNode one = new PreferenceNode("one", new PreferencePage1());
    PreferenceNode two = new PreferenceNode("two", new PreferencePage2());
    PreferenceNode three = new PreferenceNode("three", new PreferencePage3());

    //Creation of the manager
    PreferenceManager mgr = new PreferenceManager();
    mgr.addToRoot(one);
    mgr.addToRoot(two);
    two.add(three);

    //Show the preference dialog
    PreferenceDialog myPreferenceDialog = new PreferenceDialog(null, mgr);
```

The node `three` is a subnode of the node `two`.

How can I expand the node `two` in the tree of the `PreferenceNode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a subclass of `PreferenceDialog` you can override the `createTreeViewer` method and set the auto expand level:

```
@Override
protected TreeViewer createTreeViewer(final Composite parent)
{
  TreeViewer viewer = super.createTreeViewer(parent);

  viewer.setAutoExpandLevel(AbstractTreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);

  return viewer;
}
```